# Angular Material 2 : MdSelect dropdown overlay positionning

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2, private-methods, md-select

I have implemented the select component of [Material Angular](https://material.angular.io/) and the dropdown  overlay is placed over the select field like that :

[image: Select is close] [image: Select is open]

I would like to place the dropdown at the bottom of the select field.
In fact, the placement of the overlay is calculated by a private method _calculateOverlayPosition in [MdSelect](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/select/select.ts). The best solution that I found is to override this method.

However, even if this method is private, I don't know how I can do it.

Is there anyone who has already found a solution to my problem ? Or how hack a private method in typescript?

Comment: you can do that by overriding the final css, but by doing that you are not following Material design principles/guidlines.

Comment: Do you have an example ?